# Convert expanded blend to one simple vector shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to convert an expanded blend to a simple lightweight vector shape, without all these inbetween paths of all `n` steps? It seems like a complicated object to work with since computer has to recalculate all the changes that are made to the inside paths.

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot of the shape you're working with, I can try to determine if I think it could be replicated manually with gradient/gradient mesh tools, but to my knowledge there is no built in tool to convert it automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Object > Blend > Expand. Then, with all of the steps selected, go to Pathfinder and merge all the shapes together.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: merging all those generated layers keeps all paths generated in between the two original shapes and does not unite them into one shape with one gradient. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to convert it back to a single vector shape as it would have to be able to translate the blend into either a linear gradient, radial gradient, or gradient mesh.
The beauty of blends is that they aren't bound by the same rules that allow the gradient or gradient mesh tools to work, and you can get some really awesome color blends across complicated shapes.